# Notepad++ regex find and replace empty space and end of line

Tags: regex, notepad++

want to find "blank" replace it with "," start doing the same thing on the next line.

using notepad++, I have a file 100s of lines (IP addresses):

```
192.168.10.1 192.168.10.2
192.168.10.3 192.168.10.4
```

ctrl+h find "" replace with ,

```
192.168.10.1,192.168.10.2,
192.168.10.3,192.168.10.4,
```

it is very simple to find empty space and replace it with a comma",", also it I know how to find the end of the line and put a comma. however, I am struggling to tell notepad++ in the replace field to also put a comma at the end of the line. OR in the find what filed to find empty space and end of line"$".

Comment: Try `\h+|$` and replace with a comma.

Comment: Thank you. yes this worked. could you please explain to me how you this work.

Answer (score 1):

Need a little more work to avoid possible `,,` at end of line.

`(?m)(?:\h+|$(?<!\h))` replace with a comma

https://regex101.com/r/8r5ajs/1

Expanded

```
 (?m)                          # Modifier, multi-line    
 (?:
      \h+                           # Many Horizontal whitespace
   |                              # or,
      $                             # End of line
      (?<! \h )                     # If not next to a horizontal whitespace
 )
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
\h+|$
```

Replace with `,`. See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ucVuup/1).

**Details**

- `\h+` - 1 or more horizontal whitespace
- `|` - or
- `$` - end of a line.